# Replace strings in dynamically loaded content with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I used this piece of code, to replace text strings in my webpage:

```js
   function walkText(node) {
      if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        node.data = node.data.replace(/Villa/g, "Replaced");
        node.data = node.data.replace(/Apartment/g, "Replaced2");
      }
      if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT") {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
          walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    walkText(document.body);
```

```html
Villa
Apartment
```

This works fine on static content, but will not work on content that gets loaded dynamically through ajax. Is there a workaround to make this work on text that is not static/not loaded on page load?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just calling `walkText(document.body);` in your ajax success

Comment: If the ajax calls are resolved after the execution of `walkText` it is perfectly normal. You should either `await` for the calls to resolved, or call `walkText` inside the `then` method of the promise (a callback that will be executed once the promise is resolved)

Comment: You could use a `MutationObserver` on the DOM elements you know will change (or the whole document but... well, that sounds inefficient) and trigger that with `{ characterData: true, childList: true }` and then replace your stuff. Keep in mind that every replacement will retrigger the method, so prepare you new content, insert it, and in the next call don't insert it if you haven't made changes to prevent another trigger and avoid a loop.

Answer (score 0):

A basic, simple way to do this is to observe your page with `MutationObserver`. Below I have created a very simple example for this:

```js
function walkText( node ){
  
  // I needed to modify this to prevent potentially infinite loops
  // by replacing the data it could trigger another mutation event
  if( node.nodeType == 3 ){
  
    const newData = node.data
      .replaceAll( /Villa/, "Replaced" )
      .replaceAll( /Apartment/, "Replaced2" );
    
    if( node.data !== newData ) node.data = newData;
    
  }
  
  if( node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT" ){
  
    for( const child of node.childNodes ) walkText( child );
    
  }
  
}

new MutationObserver(entries => {
    
   entries.forEach(entry => {
   
      walkText( entry.target );
    
   });
  
}).observe( document.body, { characterData: true, childList: true });



document.addEventListener( 'click', event => {

  document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( 'div' ) ).textContent = 'There is Apartment about Villa';
  
})
```

The only modifications I had to make is to ensure that the text only updates when necessary, to prevent triggering an infinite loop. Otherwise, with this, it seems pretty efficient.

Docs: [MutationObserver (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 0):

Use `MutationObserver` for added nodes and replace the text:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Don't forget to disconnect the observer when you replace text otherwise you will react on own mutations and could go into an infinite loop.

```js
function changeNodes(){
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => 
    div.textContent = 'Villa or Apartment'
  );
}


function addNodes(){
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 'Villa or Apartment';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  observer.disconnect();
  
  for(const mutation of mutations){
    [...mutation.addedNodes].forEach(walkText);
  }
  
  observer.observe(document.body, {childList:true, subtree:true});
});

observer.observe(document.body, {childList:true, subtree:true});

function walkText(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    node.data = node.data.replace(/Villa/g, "Replaced");
    node.data = node.data.replace(/Apartment/g, "Replaced2");
  }
  if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT") {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addNodes()">Add nodes</button>
<button onclick="changeNodes()">Change nodes</button>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the 'observe' again inside the observer? That seems like it will just start eating up memory...

Comment: it's previously disconnected so connecting again